# Surrogate Hard Drive Mounting (cross-vendor)

Tags: hard-drive

I have a 1TB 7200rpm Hitachi hard disk drive and the read/write heads of the drive are dead (read: bent and twisted)

Can I use a Seagate Barracuda 7200rpm 1TB drive as a surrogate, and remove the disk platters from both and replace the Hitachi platters inside the Seagate?

As in, will the Seagate heads read the data written by a Hitachi drive?

Comment: I'm not sure whether the platters are compatible, but I can tell you that if you try to open the hard drive yourself and expose the platters to anything but a controlled dust-free environment designed specifically for repairing hard drives, you can just throw the thing away because chances are you won't be able to read anything off it after that. Seriously, if you knew enough about hard drives to do what you're thinking about, you wouldn't have to ask about it here.

Comment: Ha ha - oh ok.  Nuff said.

Answer (score 1):

No. For that you need **exact** model of hitachi like that dead drive. Also,you need kit for disk platters extraction, because you need replace old disk platters in new hdd case with same "angle".
So is very hard for home repair,almost impossible. Dust is your smallest problem.

Comment: Kit? What/how do you mean, specialist tools to remove the platters?

Comment: Yes,exactly. I saw it once,hard to describe it.

Answer (score 0):

Im not sure if this would help, but I had a similar issue and used this video:

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uIPZtJyrVPw

But unless you have a clean room to work in, I wouldn't recommend it.